# How to tell Outlook not to auto resize the columns of a table

Tags: microsoft-outlook, text-formatting, resizing, column, table-styles

I'm having a very frustrating experience with MS-Outlook, while creating a table inside an e-mail:

I have some text, separated by pipe characters, and I've chosen the "Convert text to table" feature to turn that text into a table. MS-Outlook does that indeed, but I don't like the size of the columns, so I would like to modify those.
I already tried resizing the columns, using the mouse, but that won't work, because MS-Outlook refuses to actually do so.
I also tried using the table properties, altering the preferred width of my table AND of columns, and whatever I modify, MS-Outlook does not care and changes it right back.
Uncheck the checkboxes also does nothing, as MS-Outlook just checks them back.
I have modified the message format standard from HTML into Rich Text but this does not make a difference.
Searching on Google came up with the following quote:

> I find this the single most frustrating feature of Table Properties, and I'm
> not sure what I tell you will be correct, but here's what eventually works
> for me (sort of):
>
> > 1. Disable auto resizing (Options... on the Table tab).
> >    ...

... but there's a problem: my "Options" page does not have any "Table" tab, as you can see:
[image]

... and even if there were, I heavily doubt it would make any difference, because the "Convert text into table" forces me to perform auto resizing, as can be seen from this dialog box:
[image]
(There's no "None" possibility)

I'm out of options. It's my intention to use my mouse to resize the columns of my "text-to-table-converted" table.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

According to your description, i notice that you want to change the column width more easily. Then you can simply place your mouse over any horizontal line of the table and drag to adjust.

[image]

---

As i know, the number next to "Fixed column width" can be modified (The range is between 0.17 and 7.3). By modifying this number, we can adjust the width of the column.

[image]

Comment: But what to do if I have clicked too fast and I would like to modify the column sizes afterwards? What to do then?

Comment: Hi @Dominique! I have updated my reply above, please feel free to check it:)

Comment: Thanks, Christy, but what you mention (modifying the column width using the mouse) is exactly what's not working: the table properties mention some "preferred width" entries (although those are not desired) and due to those settings, MS-Outlook refuses the mouse handling.